# lucene: custom scoring

Tags: lucene

I'm creating an index of simple documents of the form:

`[paragraph-id]   < numeric field (monotonically increasing ID value)
 [paragraph-text] < medium (~500 word) text field`

There are around 100K documents and they are indexed by a multi-threaded indexer that divides-and-conquers the documents so the `paragraph-id` order in which they are inserted into the index is random.

The semantics of my search system are such that the "relevance" or "score" of a document is dictated *only* by the `paragraph-id` (larger `paragraph-id` is more relevant).  I want to fully ignore what Lucene internally calculates as a "score" for the document based on standard metrics such as TF or IDF.

What's the best way to achieve this?

My "dumb" solution to this is to call the search API `IndexSearcher::search(Query q, Filter f, int max, Sort s)` with a huge `max` value (100K, so as to cover all documents) and passing a sorter to sort the results by the `paragraph-id`.

*Lucene version 3.0.2 (I know it's old, but this shouldn't matter for this question)*

Comment: If you want to customize your scoring rules, you can implement a custom [`Similarity`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) (which certainly has changed significantly since 3.0).  However, if your requirement is just to order results on some indexed value instead of on score, I'd say that using a `Sort` isn't a "dumb" solution, it's the *correct* solution.  That's what `Sort` is there for.

Comment: The problem with the `Sort` approach is that it always requires me to specify a huge `max` value.  Most of the time, I cannot present the entire result-set to the end-user so I have to end up cutting-off the results returned to me by the `search` API.  It would be nice to have Lucene do the cutoff based on the `max` value, while still implementing the scoring based on the `paragraph-id` values

Comment: @femtoRgon is right: 'Sort' is not about sorting of the first 'max' hits. It is about sorting all hits. Possible the solr-documentation will help you to understand this difference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter

Comment: @KarstenR.  Thanks.  My understanding (without trying this) was that `Score` was applied during the search (applies to every element that ends up in the result-set) and then, `max` was applied to  chop this list down to the top N hits, and *then* `Sort` was applied on these top N.  I will try out `Sort` with a smaller `max` value.  Thanks for the info